# R: split elements of a list into sublists

Tags: r, list

I have a data frame with following structure:

```
pat <- c(rep(1,50), rep(2,50), rep(3,50))
inc <- rep(c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5), rep(3,5), rep(4,5), rep(5,5),
             rep(6,5), rep(7,5), rep(8,5), rep(9,5), rep(10,5)), 3)
df <- data.frame(cbind(pat, inc))
```

df is split into a list of elements:

```
all.inc = split(df, inc)
```

Now I want to split each element of this list into sub-lists. Something like:

```
all.pat = split(all.inc, pat)
```

This doesn't work, obviously. I've already tried the `plyr` functions and `lapply`, but didn't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: But what are you actually trying to achieve? `dplyr::group_by` allows you to do arbitrary splits by one or several variables, then pipe that into an arbitrary bunch of `mutate` and/or `summarize`, then `%>% ungroup`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `lapply`:

```
lapply(all.inc, function(x) split(x, x$pat))
```

Comment: Ok, it works. As a result I'm getting a list with the same length (10) as all.inc. But I want to have each element in, for example, all.pat[1] to be a single list element. all.pat[1] has the length 1, but it should have length 3. The whole list should have length 30, in this case. Hope, this is clear?!

Comment: @Markus, that's because the list is *nested*. Indexing the sub-lists would require: `length(all.pat[[1]])`.

Comment: ok, no problem. Just found the "unlist" function. With the recursive = F option it deliveres the desired result. Many thanks!

Comment: @Markus, if that's the case, note that the solution by Ben Barnes gets you there directly (though the `data.frame`s are not in the same order).

Comment: I need both lists (all.pat and all.inc) for further processing. So I think I'll work with your solution.

Answer (score 8):

If you'd like to split your data frame all at once, you could use

```
split(df, interaction(df$pat,df$inc))
```

However, the returned value will be a single list of data frames, which is slightly different from what you would get by splitting list elements.

Comment: What's the difference between using `interaction` and `list` (`split(df, list(df$...)` here? I actually like this better than what the OP is doing because I find that dealing with nested lists can be cumbersome sometimes. +1.

Comment: @mrdwab, apparently, there's no difference (unless `identical` is lying to me). `split.default` calls `interaction` on `f` if `f` is a list, though, so I thought I'd cut out that step. If the OP is performing calculations after the first split, then splitting again, then my solution won't help. +1 to you!

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, I checked and it doesn't. It also creates a single list of (in this case) 30 data frames. I was just wondering if one method is more strongly recommended than the other--I've always used the `list` approach.

Comment: (I removed my comment because I realized it was wrong - I was thinking `tapply`-ish.

Comment: I came across this answer after answering a question today. This is very helpful. Thank you for sharing this. +1 :)

Comment: This solution is exactly what I required for something I'm currently working on.  Hadn't used the interaction function before but very useful!