# R : Error in splitting list into sublists

Tags: r, list, split, lapply

Assuming we got this dataframe

```
X <- data.frame(A = rnorm(11000, sd = 0.8),
                B = rnorm(11000, mean = 10, sd = 3),
                C = sample( LETTERS[1:24], 11000, replace=TRUE),
                D = sample( letters[1:24], 11000, replace=TRUE),
                E = round(rnorm(11000,mean=25, sd=3)),
                F = round(runif(n = 11000,min = 1000,max = 25000)),
                G = round(runif(11000,0,200000)))
```

We need to split it few times. Our goal is to get a list which look like the example below :

```
Acc : Large list (24 elements, XX Mb)
..A:List of XX
.. ..a: List of XX
.. .. ..$ 21: 'data.frame' : XX obs. of 7 variables :
.. .. .. ..$ D: num[1:XX] XXX
.. .. .. ..$ other variables
.. .. ..$ 22: 'data.frame' ...
.. .. ..$ other lists
.. ..b : List of XX
.. ..other Lists
..B: List of XX
..etc...
```

[We use this code to do this :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420994/r-split-elements-of-a-list-into-sublists)

```
Acc <- split(X,X$C,drop = TRUE)
Acc <- lapply(Acc, function(x) split(x , x$D, drop = TRUE))
Acc <- lapply(Acc, function(x,c) split(x$c , x$c$E, drop = TRUE))
Acc <- lapply(Acc, function(x,c,f) split(x$c$f, x$c$f$G, drop = TRUE))
```

At the end, we get this error :

```
Error in split.default(x$c$f, x$c$f$G, drop = TRUE) : 
  first argument must be a vector
```

Without using `c/f` :

```
Acc <- split(X,X$C,drop = TRUE)
Acc <- lapply(Acc, function(x) split(x , x$D, drop = TRUE))
Acc <- lapply(Acc, function(x) split(x , x$E, drop = TRUE))
```

We get

```
Error in split.default(x, x$E, drop = TRUE) : 
  group length is 0 but data length > 0
```

I have some questions :

1 - Is this error caused by the fact that `x$c$f`only got one element in some cases and is not consider as a vector ? **Edit** : After some other tests, seems that this point is not the problem.

2 - When I'm running my code, I get something which seems to be incorrect in the third step of splitting. Instead of looking like above : `Acc - A - a - 21`, it looks like :

```
Acc : Large list (24 elements, XX Mb)
..A:List of XX
.. ..$ 18:'data.frame'
```

So there, instead of having a list which looks like `Acc - A - a - 21`, it's `Acc - A - 21`. My question is just "why ?"

3 - Is there any function smarter than `split` / `lapply` to split and split again lists ?

I'll be glad if anyone could help.

Comment: Try `split(X, interaction(X$C, X$D, X$E, X$G), drop = TRUE)`

Comment: Where does the `c` comes from you require as an argument for the function in your second `lapply`? And what is it supposed to do?

Comment: @Veerendra Gadekar : Thanks for helping. Your answer is interesting, I'll keep it in mind. The problem is that I need to have the exact structure that I show below.

Comment: @Alex : I'll edit my post regarding your remark, thanks.